# How can I manually increment an instruction pointer from a context?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

First, let me say that I am doing things here that most people have no legitimate reason to EVER do. 99.99...% of all segfaults should result in definite termination, and merrily handling them in any but the most simple of situations WILL result in really bad behavior and a corrupted stack. If you came here looking to resolve a segfault, please look at the following link: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG35-C.+Do+not+return+from+a+computational+exception+signal+handler

That said, I am working on implementing an environment from an external standard, which has defined the behavior for returning from a computational logic error's signal handler as skipping ahead one instruction. I understand this is bad, however I have no control over it; I can't just nuke the definition, as it is for an embedded system with other software elements already written which depend on the defined behavior (they are often safety critical, and need to be able to gracefully exit, even when they do ungraceful or awful things; further I don't have source, so I can't just fix the segfault and any existing bad segfault/crash behavior is actually *desired* because I am simulating the behavior of an existing system).

While the system itself is to operate on PowerPC, which has a fixed instruction length, our development is happening in a parallel x86/x64 environment where the instructions are *not* fixed-length. I know that the following code works, albeit badly for the x86:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define CRASHME *((int*)NULL) = 0 
//for x86
#ifdef REG_EIP
#define INCREMENT(x) (x)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP]++
//for x64
#elif defined REG_RIP
#define INCREMENT(x) (x)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]++
//for PPC arch
#elif defined PT_NIP
#define INCREMENT(x) (x)->uc_mcontext.uc_regs->gregs[PT_NIP]+=4
#endif

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *vcontext)
{
    ucontext_t *context = (ucontext_t *)vcontext;
    INCREMENT(context);
}

void crashme_function(void)
{
    printf("entered new context, segfaulting!\n");
    CRASHME;
    printf("SEGFAULT handled!\n");
}

int main (int argc, char* args)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    printf("Printing a thing\n");
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
    printf("Entering new context...\n");
    crashme_function();
    printf("context exited successfully\n");
    return(0);

}
```

The result of executing this code will advance the instruction pointer by 1 on an intel based arch running Linux kernel 3.11.X, and eventually it will advance out of the instruction. I know this probably won't work on all instructions. In fact, when executed on my test environment, the handler enters 6 times (for the 6 bytes of the instruction) and then execution continues past CRASHME.

It seems like a trivial task to merely advance a given instruction pointer to the next instruction, given an existing instruction; the processor does it every cycle. In other settings it has been said "look at the instruction table and build your own" or "implement a disassembler". These are neither appropriate nor necessary for the task, as both have already been done by others and posted (almost?) exclusively in places of the web where my work computer can't go, and to which I do not trust to submit my home PC. But where can I find such tables or libraries to accomplish only doing the instruction calculation, and without looking at a site where I already know I can't access?

Comment: What would you achieve with it, if you don't even know which kind of instructions are there. You should also be aware that instructions can overlap, so if you increase 1 byte after the other, you just will hit "some" byte combination which can be interpreted as an instruction stream. And in case of an exception you don't even know where the instruction pointer is, because if the last instruction was a `ret` with some corrupted value on the stack, it can be anywhere in your addresspace.

Comment: That's why I am asking the question: I know the code I wrote will be very untrustworthy on any x86/x64 arch. It's why I need to know how to advance an arbitrary IP. I'm looking to improve the sophistication of INCREMENT(x) for x86/x64. Also, it's not really my problem; I'm not the user here, I'm the system. The user already knows this is the behavior, and it's their responsibility to kill the process from their user-implemented error handler.

Comment: You should disassembly location pointed by EIP. No. I would skip all code from offending routine, just walk through the stack to caller function (jump to a known location where you perform a return).

Comment: Completely nonconstructive remark: saying that one shouldn't return to segfaulting code because CERT does not recommend it is like saying that one should not set fire to the house one is in because smoking can cause cancer. Not that CERT shouldn't list it together with its list of “Don't write `if (x) …`” and “Don't write `if (x==0)`”.

Comment: That's why I wrote the entire second paragraph. I cannot walk through the stack to a caller function, nor jump. I MUST go to the next instruction, as that's the existing definition for the system reference document, also as per CERT, this is written specifically because a whole bunch of early programmers discover that SEGFAULTS can be handled with signal handlers and set out to write code that handles rather than crashes, instead of resolving the actual segfault (which is almost always the right solution). There's a reason in most operating systems that returning from SIGSEGV is undefined.

Comment: Handling SIGSEGV is possible and useful but only when you know what's going on. If you really need to skip an instruction (with the risk to crash again on next instruction because of garbage inputs) then I don't see any other way than a simple disassebler (through a library, probably). Honestly I never did it.

Comment: Handling yes. Returning from the handler? Not so much. It's possible on some systems, but the behavior is still undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux Kernel sources have an encoding of the X86 opcode map that is then parsed by an Awk script to generate a set of tables that can be used to read instructions. It has enough information to give you accurate instruction sizes, although you may need to extend it to include information for floating point instructions and some of the newer Intel extensions, such as AVX.

If you have access to the linux kernel source tree, take a look at arch/x86/lib/x85-opcode-map.txt.

That contains all the data you need to determine instruction sizes.

There's an AWK script @ arch/x86/tools/gen-insn-attr-x86.awk that will read the opcode file and produce a series of tables that encodes the information in the opcode map.

Finally if you look at arch/x86/lib/insn.c there's a function in there insn_get_length(...) that will give you the length of an instruction, using the tables generated from the opcode map. That should be sufficent for you to answer your particular question "how large is this instruction".

There's nothing particularly "kernely" about that code. You can adapt to user mode without doing anything special.

I'm assuming accessing the Linux Kernel sources shouldn't be a security issue for you, and that there is nothing encumbering you from reading / adopting GPL code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [libdisasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html) which should give you the information you want. I have done similar for hooking, writing my own disassembler, but I guess using a ready library is much easier.

Anyway, as I already wrote in my comment, I'm not sure what you think you gain by this. You can not really expect to analyze a program this way in an automatic fashion, and if you want it for crash recovery, I already said the reason why this is very unreliably, and may cause more problems than solving.

Maybe what you really need would be some virtual machine.

In order to execute the code you will also need a bit of assembly, which restores the registers to the state they were when the exception occured and then you jump to whereever you are pointing to.

Comment: The problem is that it's for a simulation of an embedded system, for which code has already been developed. In fact, if the embedded system crashes because it relies upon this behavior, our system is expected to display that same behavior. I asked the same questions you did about why the ARINC authors implemented such bad behaviors in their software; but ours is but to do and to die. I literally am not allowed to leave it undefined. It's been defined, and the definition must be respected. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @user2149140 Are you simulating the effect of going to the next instruction on a PowerPC processor by going to the next instruction on an x86 processor by compiling the code for the x86 instead? If so, that is not going to work, the two compiled versions could execute completely differently.

Comment: @GavinSmith I don't really know what you're asking. on a powerPC, going to context->IP+4 will go to the next instruction. It's not that simple for intel. I also know execution will be different; there may be another SIGSEGV from the following instruction. It isn't that the behavior is deterministic, merely defined. It's also, as previously stated, not my problem if some user does this thing, merely to make sure it'll return one instruction later.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to do this on an x86 when the system you are developing for is a PowerPC. The behaviour of a running program after a segmentation fault on the x86 would not tell you anything about what would happen on the real system. So you wouldn't be able to test if it was working properly.

Comment: In any case, using a disassmbler library would allow you to do it - disassembling one instruction at the current IP would give the size of the instruction, for instance. You don't explain why you can't do that.

Comment: @GavinSmith, as I understood it, the code doesn't need to behave in exact the same way. He only wants to have a similar behaviour where the outcome is really not important. On the target platform the outcome should be the dsame because apparently it behaves already like this and relies on that behaviour.

Comment: pretty much. What I can't use a disassembly library for is acting from inside a signal handler; it's fine on the x86, but in the PPC, the signal handler derps if you do too much inside of it. I need to effectively just read the instruction at IP to a table, determine how many bits to look forward based on the command to find the next piece of information I need to get past the data of the command, and feed that into the appropriate table address(ie, in x86, the command at IP is a C7;MOV: C7 00 00 00 00 00), ie what determines that there are an additional 5 bytes after the MOV command byte?

Comment: You'd have to look into the instruction manual from intel. There is the format of the instructions described, because there are some bits like the Mod R/M which determines what operands to use. The library should give you this information though.

Comment: @Devolus and hasn't that already been done, put into a neat little table tucked away somewhere on the internet, for god-knows whatever reason? I know that there's a thing, whose name I cannot recall, where it HAS already been done, but it's obscure, and they're generally located in the darkest corners of the web, where there are massive warning signs at the edge saying "Here there be virii". I also don't have the tens of hours required to collate the table myself, from Intel's obtuse manual.

Comment: A table would be to big. You have to interpret it. When I implemented my own disassembler I was also trying to do it with tables at first, but I soon realized that this doesn't work with the x86 instruction set.

Comment: Except it's already been done. I've been wracking my brain, and they're called Length Disassembler Engines. I just can't find one that isn't located at a site I would trust not to give me internet herpes, or which I could actually access from work